# Assays for protein or lipid content of insect pupae

Tags: protocol, drosophila, assay-development, mosquitoes

Does anyone have any recommendations (based on personal experience) for rapid, cheap, accurate assays for estimating protein & lipid content of individual insect (mosquito) pupae?

So far I've come across chloroform/methanol extraction for lipids, and Kjedahl procedure + Nesslerization for protein ([link](https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/19641401897)).

Mosquito pupae are not particularly tough as insect pupae go, but ideally I'm looking for personal experience that the method can cope with the sorts of sample I need to use it for.

(I strongly suspect similar assays have been developed for *Drosophila* so have added that as a tag.)